# No data displayed from DB in drop down menu

Tags: php

Echo 'Hello programmers' ;

I'm scratching my head about a pair of drop down menus. They are supposed to display all strings from the ename and mid rows. However this isn't happening and the drop down is only displaying one result from each row. There are multiple strings of test data in the actual rows.

I have some code here and perhaps you could lend a hand. Let me explain.

First off these are the methods from class dbme. To keep the clutter down the second function is exactly the same, except the SQL query for getResult() is obviously different (SELECT * from member as opposed to memberevent)

```
function openDB() {//creating database connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");
        if (!$conn) {
            $this->error_msg = "connection error could not connect to the database:! ";  
    return false;

        }

            $this->conn = $conn;
            return true;
        }



      function getResult($sql){

            $result = mysqli_query($this->conn , "SELECT * from memberevent" );
            if ($result) {
                return $result;
            } else {
                die("SQL Retrieve Error: " . mysqli_error($this->conn));
            }
        }
```

Second, this is the web-side data.

```
$db1 = new dbme();
$db1->openDB();
$sql="select mid from member";
$result=$db1->getResult($sql);// get the ids from the tables for the select

$sql1="select ename from event";
$result1=$db1->getResult($sql1);// get the ids from the tables for the select

if (!$_POST) //page loads for the first time
{
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(  );">
Select Member ID: <select name="mid">
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
echo "<option value='{$row['mid']}'>{$row['mid']} </option>";
?>
</select>
<br />
Select Event name : <select name="ename">
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
echo "<option value='{$row['ename']}'>{$row['ename']} </option>";

?>
</select>
<br />
```

I have a sneaking suspicion that a variable is getting over written, OR an extra loop is needed somewhere. But I'm not really sure, thus I post this question for advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in the SQL but never using it:

Change

```
function getResult($sql){

    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn , "SELECT * from memberevent" );
```

To

```
function getResult($sql){

            $result = mysqli_query($this->conn , $sql );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through your results inside your `getResults()` function, otherwise you will always only get one row.

Comment: Which loop would you use. I used while loop. In pseudo code, i less than 20 increment i. So that should return the result 20 times. This seemed to cause a maximum execution time error.

Comment: I tend to use `foreach($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))`, however, you can use either. Could you show me the code you've added?

Comment: Of course, this is what I had done just as a quick trial without researching all the loop options (inc the one you kindly suggested)  **function getResult($sql){
          $i=0;
while($i<=20)
            $result = mysqli_query($this->conn , "SELECT * from memberevent" );
            if ($result) {
                return $result;
                $i++;
            } else {
                die("SQL Retrieve Error: " . mysqli_error($this->conn));
            }
        }**

Comment: Ok having trouble with the formatting options on the quick reply here so bare with me.